# Помогите найти что исследовать в магистерской работе(тема уже есть)

Tags: исследование

Привет всем!

Так получилось, что тему работы мне подогнал зав.кафедры, научрук не сильно заинтересован в этой работе( Тема такая: "Исследование и разработка алгоритмов распараллеливания задач в распределенных вычислительных системах, функционирующих на мобильных устройствах". Тему можно откорректировать. Важно чтобы были распределенные вычисления и на мобильных устройствах. 
Сам я ковыряю тему уже пол года. У нас в инсте проводят смотры и на каждом смотре отчитывают. Мне уже надоело таскать разные варианты формулировки темы, цели и задачи исследования. Вот прошу здесь помощи. Учусь на кафедре информатики и ПО. Требование к теме: она связана с той что мне дали(будет отлично если будет что-то инновационное) + есть практическая польза.

Вот, пока я смог узнать что распределенными вычислениями на мобильных устройствах ***только начинают*** заниматься. Крупные фирмы взялись за это дело. Хотя, еще год назад в этом направлении мало кто думал.

**Практическая значимость?** Это сложный вопрос, все зависит от устройства, трафика, от решаемой задачи. Фиг докажешь. Я говорил на смотрах что это нужно(что мобильники уже как компы), мне сразу 100500 аргументов против, да еще какие аргументы и от кого(с профессором не поспоришь). В любом случае производительность мобильных устройств со временем только будет расти.

Я написал программу для Android, есть серверная и клиентская части. Сервер рассылает задачи, а клиент их решает. Пока примитивно, но что-то есть. Систему взаимодействия клиента-сервера хотел взять за тему, но что в ней специфичного? Думал как-то обрабатывать возобновление работы приложения на клиенте после его отключения, и тут ничего нового((( Что может тянуть на исследование???
Подсобите пожалуйста)

Comment: Тема вполне нормальная, вы же не должны скучно описать что-то где-то происходящее, а сделать научную работу. Исследования, предположения, примеры, ожидаемые caveats - это то, что и должно быть в нормальной работе.

Comment: Ну да, я понимаю. Просто есть но. Мне сказали на кафедре что исследовать распределенные вычисления на телефонах - это почти то же самое что и исследовать распределенные вычисления на компах. А последние, в свою очередь, исследованы( И задали вопрос: "что же вы там исследуете".  Я такой ээээ, ну, в принципе да... тоже что и на компах, только исследую на мобильниках и планшетах( Они к тому, что нельзя исследовать то что и так исследовано.

Comment: По мне, имеет смысл исследовать потенциал системы РВ на мобильных устройствах как таковой, с учетом ограничений для них. И что-то мне кажется, что овчинка выделки стоить не будет, разве что считать, пока тел заряжается, иначе всю батарейку высадит в раз и пользователь, оценив, что же сжирает весь заряд, грохнет РВ-клиент. Т.е. "Исследование перспектив использования мобильных устройств как платформ для распределенных вычислений".